# How to find a record from database by using find_by with two fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find a record from database in ruby on rails by using `find_by` with two fields. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Something like `User.find_by(f_name: 'ruby', l_name: 'rails')` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4 you can do:

`@user = User.find_by(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe")`

If rails 3:

`@user = User.find_by_first_name_and_last_name("John", "Doe")`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple options in `find_by`, or `where` like following:

```
User.find_by(first_field: "value1", second_field: "value2")
User.where("first_field = ? AND second_field = ?", "value1", "value2")
```